# Mailing multiple files unregarding file existence

Tags: bash, attachment, mailx

I am sending multiple files in a single mail to myself:

```
file1="/somedir/file1.md"
file2="/somedir/file2.md"
file3="/somedir/file3.md"
file4="/somedir/file4.md"
echo "Body text" | mailx -s "The Files" -a "${file1}" -a "${file2}" -a "${file3}" -a "${file4}" recipient@domain.com
```

These files are not always there, so if any of these attachments does not exist the mail will not be send. However I want to send the mail anyway with the attachments that are there. I could build an if statement with multiple other if statements nested inside of it, but that seems a bit devious. What is a better way?

Comment: you could also create missing files with `touch`which would create a new file if there isn't one there. bad side is you would send empty attachments

Comment: Would rather not send empty attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build `-a` options dynamically by filtering out non-existent files:

```
files_arg=
for file in /somedir/file1.md /somedir/file2.md /somedir/file3.md /somedir/file4.md ~/.bashrc; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && files_arg="$files_arg -a $file"
done
echo $files_arg
```

Outputs:

```
-a /home/max/.bashrc
```

Comment: Don't use a regular parameter for this; use an array.

Comment: @chepner Post your own answer then.

Comment: What if one of the files is named `updated data.md`?

Comment: @chepner Quote it.

Comment: You can't. `$files_arg` produces `-a updated data.md`, `"$files_arg"` produces `"-a update data.md"`, and `files_arg="$files_arg -a \"$file\""` just adds literal quotes to the string. You cannot safely accommodate arbitrary file names with this approach.

Comment: Almost this exact case is addressed in Bash FAQ 50, under ["Things that do not work"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#Things_that_do_not_work).

Comment: @chepner You are right. However, I never bother to handle whitespace in filenames. IMO, in 99% of cases it is a waste of time.

Comment: Already used this answer as solution since I never use spaces in file names, but good addition from chepner.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It's the other 1% of the time you should be worried about. You're not writing this answer for yourself; you're writing it for people whose use case you do not know.

Answer (score 3):

Build up an *array* of arguments (from an array of candidates, too):

```
files=(/somedir/file1.md
       /somedir/file2.md
       /somedir/file3.md
       /somedir/file4.md)


for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && attachments+=(-a "$f")
done

echo "Body text" | mailx -s "The files" "${attachments[@]}"
```

Comment: How is that better than when not using an array?

Comment: It makes sure that file names that would need to be quoted remain so.